# A geometric problem with families of congruent curves.

Tags: real-analysis, geometry, analytic-geometry, curves, plane-curves

Consider the following mapping:

In a square grid on a unit disk we shift the angles between intersecting segments, every shift in general different at different $(x,y)$ points. Take the continuum limit. The image of the gridlines (i.e. the blue lines below) will be curves with the same lengths, but will be contained in a different domain $D$ (shaded blue below right). Moreover, each family (i.e. verticals and horizontals in the disk), is composed of congruent curves (meaning that they differ just by a translation and, or, a rotation; equivalently, that they have the same curvature). The question is

> Show that Perimeter$\left(D\right)<2\pi$.

[image]

Analytically, it can be re-formulated as follows. Let's call $0<\gamma(x,y)<\pi$ the shift angle at every point. Since the image curves are congruent within each family, we have that $\gamma(x,y)=\psi(x)-\phi(y)$, being $\psi$ and $\phi$ arbitrary, not even functions (satisfying the condition on $\gamma$ for every $(x,y)\in\:$Disk). Then

\begin{align}
\text{Perimeter}\left(D\right)=\int_0^{2\pi}\mathbb{d}t\sqrt{1-2\sin t \cos t \cos\gamma(t)},
\end{align}

with $\gamma(t)=\gamma(x=\cos t,y=\sin t)=\psi(\cos t)-\phi(\sin t)$. The integrand in general varies between $0$ and $\sqrt{2}$, so it is not immediate to establish that $\text{Perimeter}\left(D\right)<2\pi$. Expanding the square root one can show that the quadratic terms satisfy some inequalities, but the linear term has no definite sign for any pair $\psi,\:\phi$. So I don't think that handling this integral expression may lead to an answer, but rather some geometrical proof/analysis using the fact the curves are congruent.

Comment: Can the mesh / cell size be infinitesimally small? How did you exclude the possibility of perimeter $ D=2π $ as invariant perimeter/boundary length in isometry? Is the problem posed by you or is it in any published reference?

Comment: The edge elements are either triangles or trapeziums.. In the given mapping inside squares become rhombuses. Edge triangles remain congruent so no change in their length sum. Trapezium border sides either expand or contract. Is the question so that total the contraction sum exceeds expansion?

Comment: @Narasimham Yes, this is considered in the continuum limit, where the number of curves is infinite and the cell size is infinitesimally small. I have not completely excluded it, but it can be shown that the only mapping that preserves the circle is the trivial one (https://mathoverflow.net/questions/432191/shrinking-a-disk-with-fixed-differential?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: @Narasimham The problem indeed comes from more generic mappings called Chebyshev mappings, which map a planar subset to a surface, but I'm restricting to the case of planar image as well. An equivalent problem is this https://mathoverflow.net/questions/433744/a-periodic-integral-inequality?noredirect=1#comment1116973_433744

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer, only a related comment. We are dealing with different geometries.

Fig 1: Sine-Gordon equation of Chebychev net  $ \alpha = 2 \psi $ is

$$ \alpha^{''}= \sin \alpha/a^2~; \psi^{''}= \sin \psi \cos \psi/a^2 ~$$

where $a$ is cuspidal radius of a pseudosphere in hyperbolic geometry.

Fig 2: When $a\to \infty $ we try to get at the flat euclidean net.

$$ \alpha^{''}=0, \quad \psi^{''}=0. ~ $$

Polar plots of the net are computed and plotted below.

( Boundary conditions taken in numerical work $\psi_i=0.12, \text{radius }r_i=0.2) $

[image]

Although similar in appearance  the hyperbolic Chebyshev and euclidean nets are not the same.

The integrands are quite different.

In Fig 1 situation

$ \psi^{'}= \dfrac{\sin \psi}{r} $ is true for a geodesic in hyperbolic geometry. When integrated $\dfrac{\sin \psi}{r}$ is a constant, represented by circles through origin, so that $ \psi^{'}$ is constant.

In Fig 2 situation

$ \psi^{'}\ne \dfrac{\sin \psi}{r} $ and $\dfrac{\sin \psi}{r}$ is not a constant.