# Does $x'(s)y'(s)$ have a geometric meaning?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, curves, plane-curves

Consider a simple, closed curve $\left(x(s),y(s)\right)$, being $s$ the arc-length.

The quantity

\begin{align}
\frac{d x(s)}{d s}\frac{d y(s)}{d s}
\end{align}

is found in [some problems](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4564878/a-geometric-problem-with-families-of-congruent-curves) concerning [Chebyshev nets](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Chebyshev_net), so I wonder if we can give to it some meaning or ascribe a property. In terms of the unit tangent $\mathbf{T}$ it can be written as $\left(\mathbf{T}\cdot \mathbf{\hat{x}}\right)\left(\mathbf{T}\cdot \mathbf{\hat{y}}\right)=\mathbf{\hat{x}}\cdot \left(\mathbf{T}\mathbf{T} \right)\cdot \mathbf{\hat{y}}$, but it apparently doesn't hint to something useful.

Comment: This quantity depends on the choice of Cartesian coordinates in the plane, hence is unlikely to be geometric.

Comment: Hard to say without more context, but $\mathrm{d}x(s) \wedge \mathrm{d}y(s)$ is an infinitesimal sector of the area enclosed by your curve; dividing by $\mathrm{d}s$ twice, one measures some "areal acceleration", in the same spirit as the areal velocity of Kepler's second law.

Comment: @Abezhiko no, the wedge product is $0$, since these are functions of one variable.

Comment: If you’re thinking about Chebyshev nets, the metric on the plane will typically not be the Euclidean metric.

Comment: @TedShifrin You're right, my bad.